# VBA AutoFill Speed Issue

Tags: excel, vba, macros, autofill

I have this piece of code which copies the formula from one cell down the column and is incredibly slow (15 minutes for a 10 thousand row sheet). The code is: `program.Worksheets("Data").Range("X2:AC2").AutoFill program.Worksheets("Data").Range("X2:AC" & LastRow)`

I have also tried putting `.AutoFill Destination` in, didn't solve the issue. I am using a `With Worksheets("Data")`, but still does not work. I also tried to insert the formulas manually, that did not work either (at all). 
Any suggestions about how could it be faster?
Thanks!

Comment: It's not the code filling the cells which takes the time, it's the calculations being performed by the formulas. The only way to speed it up, would be to write a more efficient formula.

Comment: Switch off automatic calculation during the fill and reenable it after?

Comment: Unfortunately, turning automatic calculation off and on after does not work either, because when it finishes, the columns are simply just empty, it does not fill in anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
program.Worksheets("Data").Activate
Range("X2:AC").AutoFill Destination:=Range("X2:AC" & LastRow)
```

Comment: This works as well, but just as slow as my solutions :(

Comment: To reduce the time, use `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` before run the code and  `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` after the code.